# MySQL: Unable to insert serialized value

Tags: php, mysql, serialization, insert

Never had this problem with inserting serialized values before.

I have an array called `$prefs`:

```
$prefs=serialize(array( #logged-in preferences
                    'chatMsgs'=>10,
                    'forumThreads'=>10,
                    'forumReplies'=>10
                ));
```

Which, when serialized, becomes

```
a:3:{s:8:\"chatMsgs\";i:10;s:12:\"forumThreads\";i:10;s:12:\"forumReplies\";i:10;}
```

My `INSERT` query is the following:

```
INSERT INTO `general_data`(`email`,`pw`,`name`,`adr`,`male`,`regged`,`conf`,`prefs`)
VALUES ('$email', '$pw', '$name', '$adr', $sex, NOW(), $conf, '$prefs');
```

(`male`/`sex` being a `BIT(1)`, `conf` being `int(9)` and `prefs` being `text`).

Usually my serialized queries would insert as intended, but in this particular case, I get the following error for some reason:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''a:3:{s:8:\"chatMsgs\"' at line 2.

Could anyone please provide some insight on how I could possibly fix this issue?

`EDIT`: I *can* work around this by encoding the serialized string in base64, however, this does not explain the strange behaviour of this error.

Comment: You will have to escape the serialized string before trying to insert it to database. Also try echoing your query. `$conf` is most likely empty.

Comment: Conf is a nine digit number and the same problem persisted with an escaped string as well. I will try the PDO approach and see how it goes..

Answer (score 0):

Your number one problem is not [properly escaping the values in your SQL statement](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should **NOT** be inserting user values directly into the query. Always use placeholders. A failure to escape means that you run into conflicting delimiters.

The statement should look like:

```
INSERT INTO `general_data`(`email`,`pw`,`name`,`adr`,`male`,`regged`,`conf`,`prefs`)
                    VALUES (:email, :pw, :name, :adr, :sex, NOW(), :conf, :prefs);
```

Then using [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) you can bind against those placeholders. `mysqli` is an alternative that uses `?` instead.

If you insist on using the creaky, dangerous, deprecated `mysql_query` you will have to call `mysql_real_escape_string` on any and all values interpolated into your query string.

Comment: There is no need for escaping any of the data here as it has been properly sanitized beforehand.